# d3 key rollups using quantiles

Tags: javascript, d3.js

right now I have:

```
var data = d3.nest()
.key(function(d) { return d.chiGroup; })
.key(function(d) { return d.incGroup; })
.rollup(function(v) { return d3.mean(v, function(d) { return d.grant; }); })
.entries(input);
```

Is there a way to get the 25% or 75%? I was thinking of something like `return d3.quantile(v, function(d) { return.dgrant;},.25)` but `quantile` does not take an accessor function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
var data = d3.nest()
.key(function(d) { return d.chiGroup; })
.key(function(d) { return d.incGroup; })
.rollup(function(v) { return {
    first: d3.quantile(v.map(function(d) { return d.grant;}).sort(d3.ascending),.25),
    median: d3.median(v, function(d) {return d.grant;}),
    last: d3.quantile(v.map(function(d) { return d.grant;}).sort(d3.ascending),.75)
} ;})
.entries(input);
```